# How can I create two combobox from one store in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

How can I add two comboboxes from one store store have `type` field witch values can be `1, 2 and 3` I want records with type `1 and 2` in first combobox and `2 and 3` in second.

**My ComboBox:**

```
Ext.define('Exp.view.settings.servers.ComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias : 'widget.server_combobox',

    xtype: 'combobox',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    name: 'server',
    store: 'Servers'
});
```

**Store:** (just example data from server with json reader)

```
Ext.define('Exp.store.Servers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Exp.model.Server',

    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,

    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Server 1',
        type: 1
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Server 2',
        type: 3
    },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Server 3',
        type: 2
    }]
});
```

If I go with store filter both comboboxes goes filtered. For now I created two stores but that means two ajax calls to server and I don't really like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, you can not. If you need to have two different sets of data from the same store to be reflected in any two UI elements at the same time (two grids or two combos or whatever) you need to create a copy of your store.

You can either clone it or even create more simple model (comboboxes need just value and name for example) but there is no way around it.

Comment: Is there easy way to clone store?

Comment: You would have to do a loop. Go through all records and add them to the new store... I think you can find many sample for this task. It's not hard

Comment: Thanks. Just thought maybe  extjs have some not documented magic function :D

Answer (score 1):

I think filter will be cleanest way. 
it's just local example. Didn't used app structure.
http://jsfiddle.net/ssxenon01/WpZMU/

Comment: Problem is same when I select in first combobox it works but when I click on second first goes filtered as well.. your example dindn't work at least for me. Is it incomplete?

Comment: forget my first example just create 1 store and clone it, that's much better ;)

Comment: also I have grid with same store that's problem too. Thats why I failed with filter. Hmm clone maybe would ok, but what when I add some values in original store?

Comment: And u can listen change event and re clone ur 2nd store again ;)

Comment: seems like a hack for hack :D but maybe worth a try :D